# override IEnumerable .NET

Tags: c#, .net

We are working on adapting some 3rd party code, by extending the base class into a derived class that we can adjust. All is working well apart from one method that returns IEnumerable.

We have created some sudo code to test exactly where the problem is and it can be recreated with a simple example.

In the example, below the code block within the method never gets called; we have put breakpoints in there, we have added an exception to be thrown straight away. The result is always the same, the debugger just skips over the line.

Can someone explain what we are doing wrong? Is it possible that the 3rd party code simply does not work either?

```
public class Test
{
    public virtual IEnumerable GetList(Type type, string key)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Test2 : Test
{
    public override IEnumerable GetList(Type type, string key)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
        {
            yield return x;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var x = new Test2();
        var y = x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test") as List<int>;
}
```

EDIT: Lot of good answers, in short the issue was the yield keyword. As this is a 3rd party implementation, i could only change code within the virtual method. In the end, i ended up returning an IEnumerable from it rather than yield returning from the loop.

This has made the code work within the 3rd party library.

Comment: Since it is an iterator method, your code in the method is not actually entered until enumeration starts, e.g. with a `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression:

```
x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test") as List<int>;
```

...returns `null` without enumerating anything, because the runtime type of the iterator returned by the method is not `List<int>` and can't be cast to `List<int>`.

`x.GetList(...)` returns an iterator object that's fairly trembling with eagerness to rip through all those `yield return` statements, but then you check to see if it's actually a `List<int>` instead. Finding that it's not a `List<int>`, you toss it aside.

Clearly this wasn't your intent, but that's how the `as` operator works in C#.

If you want a `List<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`, you have to call `ToList()` on it. Casts of reference types in C# don't do anything special under the covers unless you've got a [conversion operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx), and the framework doesn't supply those in cases like this. I think that's wise. I'm not a fan of conversion operators. They tend to be one of those helping hands that rips your arm off when you least expect it, like overriding `Equals()`.

As @Letseatlunch points out, you ideally ought to be returning `IEnumerable<int>` rather than `IEnumerable`, but since it's an `override`, I would guess that's not an option. But that means that to go LINQy with it, you'll have to add `Cast<int>()` or something:

```
var listofints = x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test").Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because you are casting to `List<int>`

```
var y = x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test") as List<int>;
```

try:

```
public class Test
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<int> GetList(Type type, string key)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Test2 : Test
{
    public override IEnumerable<int> GetList(Type type, string key)
    {
       for (var x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
       {
           yield return x;
       }
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new Test2();
    var y = x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test").ToList();
}
```

Note that GetList is returning `IEnumerable<int>` now instead of `IEnumerable` since IEnumerable has ToList.

Comment: Just to complete your answer... `yield return` causes the code not to be evaluated until collection is enumerated (call to `.ToList()`)

Answer (score 1):

This happens **not** because of casting, but because of `yield` implies an iteration, and none forces any kind of iteration, so nothing happens. To prove it, just rewrite the same code without casting, like this

`var y = x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test");`

- the same incorrect outcome, like before.

To correctly use your function, as is it was implemented, you need to call inside 
a loop, for example:

`foreach(var i in x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test")) {}`

, or use some other method, like `ToList()` that forces collection to enumerate.

**Now** your method actually would be invoked.

Comment: That's not exactly right. For example if his original Test2.GetList returned 'return new List<Int32>();' instead of using yield then casting would cause the method to be invoked and is not the same as var y = x.GetList(typeof(decimal), "test");

Comment: @Letseatlunch: my point is that, the problem is not because of "casting" by itself, but because of lack of enumeration invocation. we can achieve that in different ways.

Comment: you're right that the problem is not because of "casting" by _itself_ but the problem is that because it's cast to List<int> and returns null it can _never_ be enumerated. As you showed if he doesn't do the casting he can use his method as is.